# Does the Brightcove 508 compliant player support the Javascript API?

Tags: section508, brightcove

First, the Brightcove forums are useless, since you must have a Brightcove account to contribute. IA m just a dev, no account.

I have been given the source for the Brightcove 508 compliant player and need to do some simple things (stop, start, jump) using the Javascript API.

No need for code here, a standard player accepts the calls fine, the 508 does not. Why is that?

Does API support have to be specifically turned on when the player is generated?

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "the 508 does not." This doesn't make any sense. Do you mean the things you are adding are not compliant/accessible?

Comment: See the reference in the paragraph above "508 compliant player". So, the 508 complaint player does not accept the Javascript API calls. It turns out that this is an issue of player setting rather than player types. I'll ignore the tone of your comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there's a flag in the player (template, if I remember correctly) that enables API access. 
I think the point there is that if you don't own the player, you shouldn't control how it behaves.

[BC support docs](http://support.brightcove.com/en/docs/editing-settings-players-global-tab)